# Rails 4: coffeescript conditional display based on select field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, coffeescript, conditional-statements

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following form (related to my `Post` model):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :format, "FORMAT" %>
  <%= f.select :format, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] %>
</div>
```

Which renders the following html code:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="post_format">FORMAT</label>
  <select name="post[format]" id="post_format">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</div>
```

Now, I need to display a specific message on the page, inside `<div id="post_format_analysis"></div>` and in real-time (without page reload), depending on which option the user selects.

So, I tried this in my `posts.coffee` file:

```
$(document).ready ->
  post_format = document.getElementById("post_format")
  if post_format.options[post_format.selectedIndex].value == 'A'
    $('#post_format_analysis').html 'GREAT'
  else if post_format.options[post_format.selectedIndex].value == 'B'
    $('#post_format_analysis').html 'GOOD'
  else if post_format.options[post_format.selectedIndex].value == 'C'
    $('#post_format_analysis').html 'OK'
  else if post_format.options[post_format.selectedIndex].value == 'D'
    $('#post_format_analysis').html 'BAD'
```

The problem is, this only works the first time the page is loaded, ie: the message (**GREAT**) corresponding to the value selected by default (**A**) is displayed.

However, when the user selects another value, the message is not updated.

I believe the problem is that I initialize the code with `$(document).ready ->` while I should also initialize it when there is a change in the value of the `#post_format` div but I am not sure of how to make this work.

Any idea?

Comment: wrap the if else inside a change event binding.  `$('#post_format').on 'change', ->`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a way to also take into consideration the selected value on page load, so the right message is displayed even when the user first loads the page, not only when he selects a different value? Something like `$('#post_format').on 'load, change', ->` maybe?

Comment: Or with a `preventDefault` maybe?

Comment: just call `$('#post_format').change()` after binding.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Feel free to offer this solution as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that it doesn't observe changes in the select field's value.  You can achieve this by placing that whole code inside a change event binding callback.  I'm also suggesting a small refactoring so your code looks a lot cleaner.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#post_format')
    .on 'change', ->
      grades = { 'A': 'GREAT', 'B': 'GOOD', 'C': 'OK', 'D': 'BAD' }
      $('#post_format_analysis').html grades[@value]

    .trigger('change')
```